# How can I get a string that is next to another string?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I am creating a batch program, and you need to pass arguments to it.
Though with my current code you have to pass the arguments in a certain way.
The way I could fix this is by getting a line of text next to the argument.
This is what I want :

```
batch.bat -arg2 arg -arg1 arg
                 ^         ^
                 |         |
              Need This Need This
```

Comment: Well `batch.bat` will see your required arguments as `%2`, _(string following `-arg2`)_, and `%4`, _(string following `-arg1`)_, is that what you wanted to know? or is there something else you wanted? Also you may be interested in the `Shift` command, please open a Command Prompt window and enter `shift /?` to read its usage information.

Comment: OK, here's my problem: My batch file has 2 different arguments, let's say -1 and -2. Those 2 arguments are required, but the user could get the order messed up, Which will make my batch file behave in a weird way. For example, batch.bat -1 arg1 -2 arg2. They are in the correct order. But batch.bat -2 arg2 -1 arg1? It will make my batch file behave in a weird way. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a skeleton to use. If you don't trust your users, you will have to add some precautions (like checking if arguments come in pairs or if the first argument of a pair starts with a `-` and the second doesn't)

```
@Echo Off
setlocal
:loop
if "%~2" == "" goto :continue
set "%~1=%~2"
shift
shift
goto :loop
:continue
REM check the parameters:
set - 2>nul
```

Try with

```
batch.bat -arg2 world -arg1 hello
```

Alternative syntax (without changing the code):

```
batch.bat -arg2=world -arg1=hello
```

(maybe better understandable by users)